# DataTable and DataGrid integration

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I want to use `DataTable` for the WPF `DataGrid`. I actually got it working in a sample program I made months ago, yet I won't find the source. So, I tried this.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="291" Width="800">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="180" Header="Name" CanUserResize="False"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Position}" Width="180" Header="Position" CanUserResize="False"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=E-Mail}" Width="280"  Header="E-Mail" CanUserResize="False"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
var contacts = new DataTable();

contacts.Columns.Add("Name");
contacts.Columns.Add("Position");
contacts.Columns.Add("E-Mail");

foreach (var x in y)
{
    contacts.Rows.Add(x.foo, x.bar, x.foobar);
}

dataGrid.ItemsSource = contacts.DefaultView;
```

However, the columns seem to be added twice:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **AutoGenerateColumns** property of Datagrid to **false**

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll add it as accepted answer as soon as I can.